# traefik Incorrect TXT record

Tags: traefik

**It seems to be a bug https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3468**

---

I have a problem with Traefik's ACME client, I've tried version 1.6.5 and version 1.7.0-rc2.

I want to use wildcard domains. (I've replaced my real domain with my.domain).
So I need certificate for `my.domain`, `foo.my.domain` and `foo2.my.domain`.

As described here : https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains I can use this :

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.my.domain"
  sans = ["my.domain"]
```

But I get this error :

```
traefik       | time="2018-07-20T08:59:44Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"*.MY.DOMAIN,MY.DOMAIN\" : cannot obtain certificates: acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[MY.DOMAIN] acme: Error 403 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized - Incorrect TXT record \"cNypmmpPd4tlKS4nAIZTft_PsUqVNmmK87x0KVV3SfM\" found at _acme-challenge.MY.DOMAIN\n
```

And you have to know, **with this configuration all is working good**

```
  main = "my.domain"
  sans = ["foo.my.domain", "foo2.my.domain"]
```

If it works with that why wouldn't it work with wildcard?

I'm using `dns cloudflare` and txt is correctly added to dns.

Thanks to all

---

**It seems to be a bug https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3468**